# How does Electro know Spider-Man's identity in No Way Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In Spider-Man: No Way Home, Doctor Strange mentions that the spell pulled in villains who knew Spider-Man's identity.

When did Electro find out that

> Peter Parker

is Spider-Man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a throwaway line in the film about him "absorbing data". Presumably that data included Spider-Man's secret identity.

> "I was whoopin' Spider-Man's ass, he'll tell you! And then, he caused
> an overload. **I was stuck in the grid, absorbing data.** I was about to
> turn into pure energy, and then... oh shit. I was about to die."

That being said, assuming this Electro is the same Electro from The Amazing Spider-Man 2, he might have overheard Gwen say Peter's name during their battle.